# Как объединить три условия в одну проверку?

Tags: c++

Мне надо этот код, выполнить в одном условии `if`

Если хоть одно из двух условий верно `bind` или `listen`, тогда выполнить что задумано.

Проблема в том что там `SocketType == SOCK_STREAM` что является третьим условием.

```
        if (bind(ServSock[i], AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

            closesocket(ServSock[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (SocketType == SOCK_STREAM) {
            if (listen(ServSock[i], 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

                closesocket(ServSock[i]);
                continue;
            }
        }
```

И еще покажите вариант если все проверки не верны, выполнить условия.

Comment: лучше  просто выполнить код, если условия не верны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так

```
    if (bind(ServSock[i], AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR 
    || SocketType == SOCK_STREAM && listen(ServSock[i], 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ServSock[i]);
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можно еще вариант если все проверки не верны, выполнить другое условия?

Comment: Какая та ошибка в коде найти не могу где.

Comment: if (bind(ServSock[i], AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR 
    || SocketType == SOCK_STREAM && listen(ServSock[i], 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ServSock[i]);
            continue;
        }
    } else { // "выполнить другое условия"

Comment: может скобок надо понаставить, а то я как для с# написал

Comment: Код работает но надо именно проверку на все варианты, если абсолютно все неверно.
а точнее bind и listen не верны вместе.

Comment: if(!(те же условия)){.....}

Comment: Всего 3 проверки, одна все верно, верно что то одно и абсалютно неверно ничего.

Comment: спс это подошло

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассмотрим условие с двумя выражениями:

```
if  (Expr1 || Expr2) {
    //выполнить код "A"
    continue;
}
```

Означает: если один из выражений верно, игнорировать остальной код. Причем, сначала проверяется первое выражение, поэтому туда нужно записать приоритетное.
Каждое выражение может состоять из нескольких других выражений. В вашем случаи `Expr2` состоит из двух выражений:  `Expr2 == E1 && E2` Т.е. для выполнения условия оба выражения должны быть истинны. А значит можно записать:

```
if  (Expr1 || (E1 && E2)) {
    //выполнить код "A"
    continue;
}
```

Означает: если истинно первое выражение  или два других, то выполнить код "A"
Но тут, по мне, незачем пихать лишнюю операцию `continue;` Поэтому предложу другие, эквивалентные варианты, которые просто  выражают что нужно делать при невыполнении условия:

```
if  (Expr1 || (E1 && E2)) {
    //выполнить код "A"      
}
else { 
    // выполнить код "B"
```

}

Или другой, по мне наилучший вариант (если не учитывать читабельность), так как тут нет обязательной проверки какого то выражения, если предыдущее истинно:

```
if  (!(Expr1 || !(!E1 || !E2) ) {
    //выполнить код "B"      
}
else { 
    // выполнить код `"A"`
}
```

Означает: если неверно первое, то проверить два  других, и если хотябы одно из выражений не верно,  то выполнить код `"B"` иначе  `"А"` (в вашем случаи вызов функции closesocket(ServSock[i]);)

Другой, эквивалентный вариант:

```
if  (!Expr1 && (!E1 || !E2) )) {
    //выполнить код "B"      
}
else { 
    // выполнить код "A"
}
```

Тут минус в том, что компилятору придется проверить как минимум два условия (Expr1 и E1), независимо от того, истинно ли первое условие, и тут, нужно отметить, что на проверку условий уходит больше времени, чем на много других операций...

Comment: У меня вопрос посложней, как сделать из этой функции

`if  (!( Expr1 || (E1 && E2) )) {` еще лучше
то есть, если оба варианта буду не верны, выполнить еще две проверки, иначе выполнить условия код B. true

Скажем еще E3 || E4 надо проверить если два варианта дали folse

Comment: Получается проверка в проверки, какая та без условий внутри else

Comment: Хотя ладно я наверно загнул, такие штуки лучше не создавать, их же наверно вообще сложно понять. Скорее всего лучше просто вложенность if else 3 раза сделать

Comment: ничего сложного не вижу, наоборот ваша вложенность условий хуже по читабельности. И никакого проверка в проверке нет внутри else, а просто выполняется другой код, если условие не выполняется.  Я же вам говорил, что любое выражение может состоять из других выражений.  E3 || E4 или еще какие то другие, проверку можете выполнять аналогично